# jQuery AJAX - Check if logged in without displaying dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, passwords

I have a password protected website running on WinCE that, upon attempting to access the secure pages, will automatically fire up the built-in browser log in box using `WWW-Authenticate`.

I want to be able to test whether the user is logged in or not by accessing that page.  The issue is that when I try this using a jQuery ajax request the browser pops up the login box as it would if the user had navigated there!  How can I prevent the login box from opening and instead have jQuery just throw an error instead

Running the following code:

```
$.ajax({
url: '/web/secure/securepage.html',
success: function(data){ console.log(data) },
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
      }
});
```

Makes this box appear instead of just failing with an error message

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using HTTP authentication. If the client is not logged in you *will* get login box (AJAX or otherwise).

If it is possible for you to keep an insecure page within the path `/web/secure/` then you can try to create an ASP 'login test' page as follows:

1. Create an insecure ASP page (without HTTP authentication) in the folder `/web/secure/`. You can name it like `/web/secure/logintest.asp`.
2. Send the AJAX request to `/web/secure/logintest.asp` (it is the page you created above. Since it's insecure you won't get the login popup).
3. Check on the ASP page whether the request headers contain an `Authorization` value (e.g. `Authorization: Basic amltbXk6cGFnZQ==`) using `Request.ServerVariables("Authorization")`. If the header value *exists* it means the user is authorized and send the success status code (200) else send a client failure code (4xx).
4. Check the response of your AJAX request on the client and do your stuff.

Try reading through ASP for Win CE [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms834461.aspx#webserver30_asp).

The thing I am counting on here is that once the HTTP authorization is successful the browser always sends the `Authorization` header for consecutive requests under the same server path (hence the need to create the insecure page within `/web/secure/`). If the user is logged in you will be able to judge it by retrieving the header on the ASP page.

Comment: Very good idea actually, unfortunately I don't seem to be sending the Auhtorization header unless I am requesting an authorized page, I'll have a play see if I can make it work

Comment: @Chris You don't need to send it. The browser sends it on it's own if the user has logged in with HTTP authentication successfully.

Comment: Sorry what I meant was, when I make a connection and check what HTTP headers were sent then I do not see the Authorization header.

Answer (score 0):

Chris, you can actually add a condition in your login page that if the url consists of username and pass value , then u can apply those values to your login fields and initiate the button click using javascript or jQuery.

chances are there one can trap this values over the url, but since the submission happens in flick of a milliseconds, i guess it wouldnt matter.

Comment: @chris if required u can encrypt it over the channel and decrypt it again on your login page .it all depends on secure u want to keep your application .

Comment: Hi - thanks for the answer but the login page isn't a custom one, its the default browser modal dialog that pops up when using `WWW-Authenticate`

Comment: @chris : you can even send via jquery ajax call, since its a asynchronous call